# state not updating on scrolling in React component?

Tags: reactjs, scroll, use-state

I have a react component, HomeScreen.js:

```
import React, { useEffect,useState } from "react";

const HomeScreen = () => {
  const [scrolledY, setScrolledY] = useState(0);
  const handleScroll = () => {
    const scrollY = window.scrollY;
    setScrolledY(scrollY);
    console.log(scrolledY);
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
  }, []);
  return (
    <div
      className="homeScreenContainer"
    >
    </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Why is scrolledY not getting updated when I scroll?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it. I just had to add the scrolledY state as useEffect's dependency;

```
useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
    return () => {
    window.removeEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
    };
  }, [scrolledY]);
```